# Meaning of "it turned his brain"

Tags: meaning

What does this uncommon phrase mean? Does it mean "it made his head spin"? Or maybe it means "it went to his head"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most contexts it will mean that it made him mad (insane, not angry).

Comment: I don't remember hearing this idiom, but I did a search for some examples, and this interpretation seemed to explain most of them pretty well.

Comment: I believe it uses turned in the sense of going rotten. I agree that this is the proper meaning.